# A list of positive matrices by MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What is the program (in MATLAB) which has an answer to the following question.

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n$ be a natural number. We are just supposed to focus on $M_n(Z_p)$, the set of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in the field $Z_{p}$.

Definition. We say that a matrix $A$ is $k$-positive if there are matrices $X_1,\cdots,X_k$ in $M_n(Z_{p})$ with $A=X_1^tX_1+\cdots+X^t_kX_k$ ($X^t$ 
is the transpose of $X$).

Problem. List all (pairwise different)  $k$-positive matrices where $k=1,2,\cdots$.

Comment: What are your thoughts and what have you tried...? There are only finitely many matrices in $M_n(Z_p)$ so you could do everything by brute force (might take a while for large $p,k,n$ though).

Comment: @Surb Could you please make more clarify?  brute force?!

Comment: Well, you can list all matrices in $M_{n}(Z_p)$, and then list all matrices which are $k$-positive. Finally, you can clean the duplicates. But this is combinatorially slow.

Comment: You will have $p^{n^2}$ elements in $M_n(Z_p)$ and then at most $\binom{p^{n^2}}{k}$ possible $k$-positive matrices. So you can build them, take these constructions modulo $p$ and clean the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your hint but I think the program would not be straightforward! Since as for $k$-positive matrices, we have to consider any arbitrary $k$-tuple matries $X_1,\cdots,X_k$.

Comment: well, it *is* straightforward, but very very slow.